# Implementing Parcelable interface on polymorphic arrays

Tags: android, oop, inheritance, serialization, parcelable

I have an array of type named `ItinerarySegment`, and this type has subclasses: `WalkSegment`, `BusSegment` etc.

```
public interface ItinerarySegment
{

}

public class WalkSegment implements ItinerarySegment
{

}

public class BusSegment implements ItinerarySegment
{

}
```

What sort of strategy should I follow when making the array of `ItinerarySegment` parcelable? The main concern here is how it will be used later when re-constructing the array via the [createTypedArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createTypedArray%28android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E%29) method (prepared by [writeTypedArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeTypedArray%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) method).

In which the [createTypedArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createTypedArray%28android.os.Parcelable.Creator%3CT%3E%29) method take a [Creator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html) field parameter. The problem lies here...Where should the [Creator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html) field be defined? (in `ItinerarySegment`, `WalkSegment`, or `BusSegment`?).

```
public static final Creator<Typename> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Typename>()
{
    public Typename createFromParcel(Parcel in)
    {
        return new Typename(in);
    }

    public Typename[] newArray(int size)
    {
        return new Typename[size];
    }

};
```

If I make `ItinerarySegment` an abstract class and define the [Creator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html) field's method, then the subsequent subclasses's data will be lost since neither of their constructors are called with the Parcel parameter, instead `ItinerarySegment`'s constructor will be called.

```
constructor(Parcel in);
```

If I make `WalkSegment` define [Creator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html) field, then `BusSegment` would have a problem.

Any clarification needed?

Answer (score 4):

In order to do this using `writeTypedArray()` and `createTypedArray()` you would need to make `ItinerarySegment` an `abstract class`, not an `interface`. `ItinerarySegment` would need to implement `Parcelable` and it would need to have a `CREATOR` defined that would be called to unmarshall the `Parcel` and create new objects. Derived classes would also need to implement the methods `writeToParcel()`, `describeContents()` and the `CREATOR`.

NOTE: Because `writeTypedArray()` does NOT write the type of the object into the `Parcel`, you will need to do this yourself. Here's 2 possible ways:

1. The `writeParcel()` method of each derived class would have to write something to the `Parcel` at the very beginning that identifies its type (a `String` or `int` value).
2. The `writeParcel()` method of each derived class would have to call `super.writeToParcel()` before writing anything to the `Parcel`. In the `ItinerarySegment.writeToParcel()` method you could figure out what type of derived class it is and write something to the `Parcel` that identifies its type (a `String` or `int` value).

The `CREATOR` in `ItinerarySegment` would first read the identifier from the `Parcel` and then using that, determine which type of object to instantiate. It would then call the corresponding object's `CREATOR` to actually instantiate the object and return that to its caller.

This basically works like an object **factory**, in which the base class knows how to instantiate different types of its own derived classes.

The downside of all this is that the abstract base class would have to know about all of its derived classes. I suppose you could also do this dynamically, by have all derived classes call a static method in the base class passing its "type" and `CREATOR`, which the base class would then store in an array to be used as needed.

All doable, but pretty complicated.

As an alternative you can use `writeParcelableArray()` and `readParcelableArray()`, where the class name of each object is written to the `Parcel` so that it knows which `CREATOR` to call when unmarshalling.

IMHO the only time to use `writeTypedArray()` and `createTypedArray()` is when all the objects in the array are instances of the same class, and you are writing more than a handful of them into the `Parcel`. In that case, you save the overhead of writing the class name into the `Parcel` for each object, as you know they are all the same. In this case you don't need to go through all the agony I described above because you know the type of all objects beforehand (no polymorphic types).

I realize this answer is probably more than a year late, but what the heck. Maybe it will help someone else ;-)

Comment: I realize that this comment is more than a year late :-) but, yes, your answer is helpful. I was wondering how Java unpacked polymorphic parcels into the correct types ... and now I understand that it doesn't. :-(  That's a pity, but the factory approach you suggest should work.